# Access to project.lock.json is denied on RHEL - .NET Core

Tags: .net, docker, dockerfile, rhel7

I'm just starting to play with .NET Core and Docker on RHEL 7 following some instructions provided by Red Hat.

I've created a .NET core MVC app using `dotnet new -t web` and then created my `Dockerfile` in that folder, with the following content:

```
FROM registry.access.redhat.com/dotnet/dotnetcore-11-rhel7
ADD . /opt/app-root/src/
WORKDIR /opt/app-root/src/
EXPOSE 5000
RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/opt/rh/rh-dotnetcore11/root/usr/bin/dotnet restore"]
RUN ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/opt/rh/rh-dotnetcore11/root/usr/bin/dotnet build"]
CMD ["/bin/bash", "-c", "/opt/rh/rh-dotnetcore11/root/usr/bin/dotnet run"]
```

I then try to build the Docker image by running

```
docker build -t mvc_docker
```

where `mvc_docker` is both the name of the folder I'm in when I run the `docker build` command and also the name of the image I'm trying to create.

Everything looks good during the `dotnet restore` but then I get this error in the console:

> error: Access to the path '/opt/app-root/src/project.lock.json' is denied.

There is currently no `app-root` directory in the `/opt` directory in my RHEL VM - do I need to manually create one, or should I be expecting Docker to create any directories in the target directory path specified in the `Dockerfile`?

Update: So I manually created the `/opt/app-root/src` path but still get the same error, and when I `ls -la` in the `src` folder there are no files.

Is my Dockerfile content incorrect? I can run `dotnet restore` from the bash prompt in my project folder and it completes successfully but also says

> Lock file has not changed. Skipping lock file write.

But that's on the lock file in my project folder, not any file in my destination folder in `/opt`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The .NET Core image you reference was built with our source-to-image tool in mind, so your best bet is to use that.

You install it like this:

```
sudo yum install source-to-image
```

Then, enter your ASP.NET Core project's root directory (containing project.json) and use the `s2i` command to build a docker image.

```
s2i build . registry.access.redhat.com/dotnet/dotnetcore-11-rhel7 myweb-dotnetcore-app
```

And run the newly created image named `myweb-dotnetcore-app` using:

```
docker run -p 8080:8080 myweb-dotnetcore-app
```

You may need to change the ports to fit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get around the error relating to `project.lock.json` by deleting it before I ran my `docker build` command.
Doing that enabled the `dotnet restore` to complete successfully.

Sadly I am now getting another error, but that will be for a different question.